# Multi core environment drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, linux-device-driver, x86-64

Does every core has same IDTR,GDTR and LDTR values? (I think they can be different.) Are cores synched up for privilege instructions?

Comment: That's a really complex question (and is basically the same as asking: How do multicore operating systems work?). Would you mind breaking it down into pieces?

Comment: @Bjoern: Yes, that is kind of crux of question. However, I am not bothered much about user space as those things do not need to be synchronized. I want to know how hardware specific critical instructions (LGDT,LIDT or MSR changes) are executed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a coherent answer for all parts of the question. Hope someone else helps.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer your first question: Each core has its own `IDTR`, `GDTR` and `LDTR` register, but they may or may not be the same value. In the case of my multicore kernel, every core has the same memory space, therefore, I am using the same values for all the cores. However, I am not sure if it is same in other kernels.